# How to use ScalingFunctions with Graphics ChartElements

Tags: charts, scaling

How to draw spheres with BubbleChart with a reversed vertical axis?
The 3rd example shows the problem (empty plot), likely caused by the transformation, but how to correct it?

```
sample = {{4, 0, 1}, {10, 5, 0.5}};
BubbleChart[sample, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
BubbleChart[sample, 
 ChartElements -> Graphics3D[Sphere[], Boxed -> False]]
BubbleChart[sample, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}, 
 ChartElements -> Graphics3D[Sphere[], Boxed -> False]]
```

Comment: `"Reverse"` fails with `ChartElements -> Graphics[Disk[]]` as well.

Comment: I found the following desired result, but it looks like a special case, while the problem above still stands. sample = {{4, 0, 1}, {10, 5, 0.5}};
BubbleChart[sample, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"BoldScheme"}]